Why is nodemon specifically causing this "read error: 0: Resource temporarily unavailable" in my bash script when using netcat?
I have written a network client in bash using netcat which streams the stdout of a nodemon process to a remote server. This is my most complicated bash script I have written to date and the past couple of days I have been stuck at a peculiar error.
The server that receives the stream listens on two different ports. The 'main port' which is used to exchange commands such as start, stop, port numbers etc and multiple 'stream ports', each for every client node service. Of course, for this example's sake, the stream port is only one and I have hardcoded to be the port 5000;
THE SETUP:
The client script:
It requires having node and nodemon installed (preferably globally)
#/bin/bash

filename=$1
ip=$2
server_port=$3

CLIENT_FIFO="/tmp/clientfifo"
NODE_FIFO="/tmp/tmpfifo"
STREAM_PORT=5000;

mkfifo $NODE_FIFO;
mkfifo $CLIENT_FIFO;


run_netcat_wrapper(){
    port=$1
    parent_directory=$(dirname $filename)

    # Strema nodemon stdout to a a FIFO so that we can redirect it in case server sends `stop` to /dev/null 
    nodemon --watch $parent_directory $filename 2>&1 1>$NODE_FIFO &
    nodemon_pid=$!

    # Grab what comes from the FIFO and send it to the server using the stdin of netcat.
    nc $ip $port 0<$NODE_FIFO > /dev/null &
    netcat_pid=$!
}

client(){
    # Client loop which listens for incoming messages from server.
    while true
    do
        read line 
        if [ "$line" == "start" ]; then
            #run the actual nodmon wrapper in the background to continue listening for server messages
            run_netcat_wrapper $STREAM_PORT &
        fi

        # elif listen for other messages from the server...
        #                   .
        #                   .
        #                   .
        # fi

        # Not necessary but it makes the error look less violent...
        sleep 0.5
    done
}

# Biderictional setup for netcat useing a FIFO
nc $ip $server_port 0<$CLIENT_FIFO | client 1>$CLIENT_FIFO


The client index.js Nodejs service:
It just prints an integer every second to the console. This is passed as an argument to the script above.
let i = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    console.log(++i)
}, 1000);

The server commands:
nc -l -p 4000
Let's use port 4000 for our 'main port'
nc -l -p 5000
This is the stream port
These 2 commands are run on the same machine.
HOW TO RUN
After the two netcat servers have started listening, run this script on the client-side like that:
client.sh /path/to/index.js <server-ip> 4000
Then, just send the word start from the netcat server that is listening on port 4000.
THE PROBLEM!!
As you will see, on the netcat server listening on port 5000, the nodemon process keeps relaunching.
Also, at client-side, your terminal is filled with  read: read error: 0: Resource temporarily unavailable errors. It's as if the client netcat STDOUT hasn't been emptied and keeps spamming the last command it got from the server into the client function which then runs in an infinite loop because $line is equal to start over and over again, even though it has already read that.
HOWEVER:
If you change the command in the script that starts nodemon to node instead node $filename 2>&1 1>$NODE_FIFO &, NO ERRORS SHOW UP!
I have spent many many hours troubleshooting on different machines. I have read about the O_NONBLOCK flag that some programs set to the stdin, but none of the solutions worked. There have been only a couple of times where everything worked just fine with nodemon but I haven't managed to replicate those conditions. At some point, I thought that Visual Studio Code is the culprit because a few times the error appeared just when I opened a terminal window inside VsCode.
Thank you for taking the time to read all this and maybe trying to replicate and/or solve the issue.
